# Find moment generating function

Tags: statistics

I want to find the moment generating function $M(t)$ for distribution

$$
f(x) =e^{-(ax)^{2}}*(1-e^{-(ax)^{2}})^{b-1}*[-log(1-e^{-(ax)^{2}})]^{r-1}
$$

$$
M(t):=E(tX) = \int_0^\infty e^{tx}*f(x)dx
\,.
$$
But I have a problem.

Comment: not $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{tx}f(x)dx?$

Comment: thanks my friend i correct the quastion

Answer (score 0):

The moment generating function is simply the Laplace transform. Since the Laplace transform of a convolution is the product of Laplace transform you simply have to compute the Laplace transform of each term and then multiply them.